# How to receive an uploaded file which is not sent as multipart/form? PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, content-type

I got the docs from the third party that is sending me a file over http protocol and I need to write a script that will successfully receive the sent file. Content-type is set as `application/gzip` so I can't pick up the file uploaded using a `$_FILES` variable as it would be easy with `multipart/form-data`.

This link gave me a hint: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

> Note:
>   Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.

I tried to reproduce their "client" side to test my server using the example in the following url http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

And to ensure crosdomain posting is available, I used a function posted and explained by @slashingweapon [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)

There must be a way to do it - Halp!

Comment: Third party sending you URL of file ?

Comment: I think we need some additional informations. What is in the POST? Only the file? In this case, have you tried through `file_get_contents("php://input")`?

Comment: Also: I understand that 3rd part connect to your http server sending data: it is correct?

Comment: @fusion3k This is giving some results. Now I need to parse the input. It looks like a trap. Bin files might get corrupted if not done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @fusion3k who pointed me to the right direction.

`$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input")` gave the the RAW data from which I had to parse the file from. It was painful to extract it because it was a binary file. I used

1. Explode the data with "\n" as a delimiter `$rawData = explode("\n", $rawData)`
2. Skip first few lines (it was 3 lines of header data for me) and take the rest into `$valuableData`
3. Convert the last line of data from string to binary using `$convertedLine = unpack("H*", $valuableData[count($valuableData)-1])`
4. Cut out the last byte of data from the last row `$convertedLine[1] = substr($convertedLine[1], 0, -2)` ( have no idea why is `unpack returning an array)
5. `$valuableData[count($valuableData)-1] = pack("H*", $convertedLine[1])`
6. `implode("\n", $valuableData)` and write that to a file

Answer (score 0):

Hi what I understand is you just need to download the file that has been uploaded to a server, try getting the file in binary mode using the below code:

```
ftp_fget($conn_id, $file, FTP_BINARY, 0);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

The connection details must be shared with you by the 3rd party who is sharing the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that's not how it should work. Exclusively HTTP protocol is used.

Comment: You must be having a documentation given from 3rd part over how to fetch it. Can I have a look over the testing code shared with you to exactly know what is required to be done.